# Leaflet: same Marker with Tooltip and witout Tooltip

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, markers

Ho we can make a the same marker without and with tooltip???

```
var marker = L.marker([51.492098, 13.816963],{});
marker.addTo(map);

var layergroup = new L.LayerGroup();    
marker.bindTooltip('xxxxx',{permanent: true, direction:'top', interactive: true}).addTo(layergroup);
layergroup.addTo(map);
```

Comment: What is your goal ? If you create two markers at the same position, they will overlap.

Comment: Yes, i have >100 markers in a List and Wehen Click the List  i will see all by one Click without tooltip and i will Click one in a List then See this with tooltip.